# MacにApplications/XAMPP/htdocs/というディレクトリがありません

Tags: macos

MacにApplications/XAMPP/htdocs/というディレクトリがあるとのことですがありません

どうやったらでますか？

現場でつかえるPHP

XAMPPはサイトからです

Macはアプリケーション表示なので配下にファルダを作成できないのにおかしいとおもいます

仮にLAMPPだとしても http://localhost/htdocs/php/welcome.php
でも NotFound です

XAMPPです
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: 「Applications/XAMPP/htdocs/というディレクトリがあるとのこと」いったいどのような情報源にそのようなことが書いてあったのでしょうか？情報源をご質問に追記してください。他のご質問を読んでいてもよくわからなかったのですが、あなたはご自身のMacにXAMPPをインストールされたのでしょうか？もしされたのだとすれば、どのバージョンをどのような手順でインストールしたのかの情報もご質問に追記してください。

Comment: PHPの書籍に記載されてました

Comment: 書籍名と合わせて、ご質問内容を編集して情報を追記してくださるようお願いします。

Comment: 「現場でつかえるPHP」と言うのが書籍名なのでしょうか？ご自身の課題を少しでも早く解決したいとお考えでしたら、単語を並べるだけでなく、少しでも読者に何を言いたいのかが伝わるように工夫してください。過去いくつかのご質問がクローズされてしまっているのはそこらへんの工夫も配慮も見られないからではないでしょうか。「どのバージョンをどのような手順でインストールしたのかの情報」もお願いします。

Comment: あなたの疑問を解消するために必要なのは、今現在あなたのMacにどのようなソフトがインストールされてどのような設定で走っているのかと言う情報です。XAMPPの公式サイトだけでもOS X用とされるバージョンが6つもある上、様々なカスタム版が他サイトからダウンロード可能になっている可能性があります。「どのバージョンをどのような手順でインストールしたのかの情報」がご記載いただけないと、回答するのに必要な情報が記載されていない、と判断せざるを得なくなります。

Comment: バージョンによってできないことがあるのですか？

Comment: はい、そうです。

Comment: パーティションをしているのでもしかしたらルートじゃないかもしれません ルートじゃないとできないことがあるのですか？

Comment: 「パーティションをしている」と言うのはメインのディスクを複数のパーティションに区切っていると言うことでしょうか？主語(「何が？」)がわからないまま「ルートじゃない」と言われても何のことかわからないのですが、通常版のXAMPPインストーラを使ったのであれば、起動ディスクにインストールが行われるので問題になる可能性はありません。とにかく、nagonsoftware さんの回答で当質問の課題が解決したのであれば、別の課題については新たに別質問を立ててください。なお、ご質問の際には回答を書くために必要な情報をできる限りご質問本文に含めておくことをお忘れなく。

Comment: ディスクをパーティションしています また インストールされたディスクから移動させています

Comment: 別課題があるのであれば別質問を立ててください。その質問には「何を」「どこに」移動させたのかなど、必要な情報を含めておくことをお忘れなく。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finderの「移動」メニュー＞「フォルダへ移動...」を選んでください。そこに「/Applications」と入力して、「移動」ボタンを押すと、「アプリケーション」フォルダ（ディレクトリ）が開きます。注意してほしいのは、必ず先頭にスラッシュ（`/`）をつけることです。先頭のスラッシュには、起動ボリュームのトップという意味を持っています。たった記号一文字ですが、重要な意味を持っているのを、覚えておいてください。
この応用で、もしアプリケーションフォルダに、「XAMPP」フォルダあるいはアプリケーションアイコンが存在すれば、「/Applications/XAMPP」で、その中を、Finderで開くことができます。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

ここからは、老婆心からの、あるいは余計な一言と受け取られるかもしれませんが、プログラミングを習得する意思が、今後もおありなら、UNIX、Linux、macOSの絶対パスの書き方を習ってください。Linuxも、macOSも、UNIXに準拠しているので、絶対パスの書き方は共通です。
さらに、ターミナルの使い方も、入門レベルでかまいませんから、勉強して、身に付けてください。